# How could i continue this loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to output the same amount of printf  statements in both loops and i have to use for and while . Unfortunately i get a endless loop for my second loop. What I'm i doing wrong in my second loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main()
{
    int x,c,v,b;
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 25 \n");
    scanf_s("%d",&x,&c);

    for (x != 0; x--;)
    {

        printf("I'd rather be doing something else \n");
    }
    while (c!=0 ) {
        printf("Programming is easy");
        c--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf_s("%d",&x,&c);
```

in this scanf you are getting only one value.
Here variable `c` is getting some garbage value and because of that it may be running for a long time which you are thinking as endless loop.
Use

```
scanf_s("%d %d",&x,&c);
```

As per as for loop syntax.

```
for(variable initialization; condition; variable update)
```

in your code you have already having value of variable `x`.
Condition checking  `x != 0`
Variable update `x--`

so it should have to be

```
for( ;  x != 0; x--)
```

**EDIT:**
**How would i make the user prompt to enter a series of numbers until the user enters a -1 to stop.?**

Simple code you can use is.

```
scanf("%d,&a);
while(a != -1)
{
    //do work here
    //
    //
    //-----
    scanf("%d,&a);
}
```

Comment: while (c<=1 ) {
  printf("Programming is easy");
  c--;

Comment: `while (c<=1 )` should have to be `while (c >= 1 )` .

Comment: `for (x != 0; x--;)` **->**  `for (;x != 0 ;x--)` . Note the position of semi colon `;`

Comment: How could i do this using 1 input instead of 2

Comment: @ameyCU, as per as for loop syntax you are right, but this will also work fine. I will include this also in my answer.

Comment: @Himanshu I don't think so. I would expect a compilation error with correct warnings enabled .

Comment: how would i make the user  prompt to enter a series of numbers until the user enters a -1 to stop.?